# PHP: Combine form submit and file upload

Tags: php, html, forms, upload, submit

I have an online form that I submit with the following PHP code. 
This works fine and creates an email with the submitted data as required.

Now I added a simple file upload button to the form and added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form tag and tried to upload the file on the same PHP page. 
Unfortunately this is not working, however it works fine when I test the file upload on a separate form so I assume I am not using the right code to get the file data.

So far I have the following code with the line in question after the session start. 
Is there a way I can combine this successfully so that it submits the form data AND uploads the file at the same time ? (I don't need the file attached to the email, it would be enough if it gets uploaded to the server).

```
<?php
session_start();
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$varSender = $_SESSION['email'];
require_once('class.email.php');

$message="<span style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:11pt; color: #00457c;'>";
$message.="Email from:&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $_SESSION['email'] . " - ID: " . $_POST['EID'] . "<br /><br />";
$message.="<strong>User name:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . htmlentities($_POST['userName']) . "<br />";
$message.="<strong>Line 1:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $_POST['line1'] . "<br />";
$message.="<strong>Line 2:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $_POST['line2'] . "<br />";
$message.="<strong>Line 3:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $_POST['line3'] . "<br />";
$message.="<strong>Details:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />";
$message.="" . $_POST['details'] . "<br />";
$message.="</span>";

$objMail= new SendMail;
$objMail -> setTo($varSender)
 -> setTo($_POST['recipient'])
 -> setFrom('"Web Mail" <XXX@company.com>')
 -> setSubject('Web Request - ' . date('Y-m-d') . ' - ' . htmlentities($_POST['userName']))
 -> sendHTMLEmail($message);

echo "<strong>Thank you for your request.</strong><br /><br />";
echo "Your email has been submitted successfully - your ID is: <strong>" . $_POST['EID'] . "</strong>.<br />";
echo "<a href='javascript:window.close();'>Close Window</a><br />";
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of stuff to work in conjunction with your `move_uploaded_file` function.

Comment: Share your html with form

Comment: I suggest you read up on the `move_uploaded_file` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php